# how to use .properties file of BWCE at the time of deployment

Tags: deployment, tibco

I am working on deployment of a BWCE application on Openshift, i received. properties file from developers separately, not in root directory.

1. Now how to use this. properties file at the time of deployment
2. can i push this .properties file in root directory of github
3. how to call this properties file at the time of deployment.

Comment: In which format is your file ? is it a BW 6.X XML profile file or a simple properties file ?